# Denpendencies update from an old polkadot version

Tags: upgrade, crates-io

We have been using polkadot/substrate `v0.9.42` version and want to catch up with the latest release (v1.6.0+). I'll make sure to check each version's [release analysis](https://forum.polkadot.network/tag/release-analysis) on the polkadot.forum, but still I've got two general questions:

1. Is it possible/recommended to do discrete version upgrade, like `v0.9.42` => `v1.0.0` => `v1.5.0` => `v1.7.0` (just as an example), or is there any version that can't be skipped?
2. I notice that crates.io crates are now being used, given that each of them seems to follow its own semVer (e.g. `sp-io` and `sp-std` have different versioning), how can I easily find out the versions of each related crate for a specific polkadot release?

I'd appreciate for any help!

Comment: Also awaiting for answer.